# How to convert a String to an Integer or Float in Crystal?

Tags: type-conversion, crystal-lang

**In Crystal, how can I convert a `String` to an `Integer` or `Float`?**

Using Python I can simply do the following:

```py
>>> nb = "123"
>>> int(nb)
123
>>> nb = "1.23"
>>> float(nb)
1.23
```

Are there any similar tools in Crystal?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [**`String#to_i`**](https://crystal-lang.org/api/latest/String.html#to_i(base:Int=10,whitespace:Bool=true,underscore:Bool=false,prefix:Bool=false,strict:Bool=true,leading_zero_is_octal:Bool=false,&)-instance-method) and [**`String#to_f`**](https://crystal-lang.org/api/latest/String.html#to_f(whitespace:Bool=true,strict:Bool=true)-instance-method) methods:

```rb
"123".to_i # => 123

"123".to_i64 # => 123 as Int64

"1.23".to_f # => 1.23

"1.23".to_f64 # => 1.23 as Float64
```

etc.